# Freemarker assign list length to local variable

Tags: exception, variable-assignment, freemarker

The following freemarker code causes an exception

```
<#assign i= it.getList().size()>
<#list it.getList() as elem>
    <#if i==1>
    <li>${elem.name}</li>
    <#else>
    <li class="marked">${elem.name}</li>
    </#if>
    <#assign i = i-1>
</#list>
```

The following exception is thrown:

> Expected hash. it.getList() evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleSequence

Anyone knows why? How can i assign the length of the list to my variable `i`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I figured out, that it did not understood the syntax for the `size` [built-in](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_size). 
The right syntax for assigning the size of a list to a local variable is

```
<#assign i = it.getList()?size>
```

Comment: Works perfectly !!