# Freemarker template exception

Tags: java, templates, exception, freemarker

In my java code i create a List of A , and then `add` one instance of `A` to the list.
I am passing this list to the freemarker template and my template code is as follows:

```
<#if listA.size()!=0>
 <#list listA as A>
 ${A.getA()}
 </#list>
<#else>
nothign
</#if>
```

The error that I get is

`freemarker.template.TemplateException: Expected hash. listC evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleSequence on line 1, column 3 in null.`

I am nt sure why is it saying anything about null? What is wrong, kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, and here is the question.
apparently it does not understand the syntax of size method.

[Freemarker assign list length to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864022/freemarker-assign-list-length-to-local-variable)

Comment: It understands the syntax. Its problem is that the type of `listA` is not hash, so it can't have sub-variables.